# Pandas select top 3 and append from another table

Tags: python, pandas, relational

Hi I would like to take the top 3 numbers for each person and
and append the reason_comments into them.
If there is a tie, I would like to just take the first one.

May i know how can i do this in python please?

```
Table 1:
      id    VarA    VarB    VarC    VarD    VarE
        1   5        4       3       2       1
        2   4        6      21       5       5
        3   3        8      6        9       0
        4   7        8      23      44       0

Table 2: 
    reason_code reason_comment
    VarA        A is high
    VarB        B is high
    VarC        C is high
    VarD        D is high
    VarE        E is high


Results:
id  reason 1    reason 2    reason 3
1   A is high   B is high   C is high
2   C is high   B is high   D is high
3   D is high   B is high   C is high
4   D is high   C is high   B is high
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possible ties, so is necessary remove them. So you can reshape DataFrame by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and remove duplicated by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

```
df1 = (df.melt('id')
        .sort_values(['id','value'], ascending=[True, False])
        .drop_duplicates(['id','value']))
```

Then for filter top3 is used [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for possible reuse it for new column names in [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1) 
    
df1 = df1[df1['g'].le(3)]
```

Also use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for data by another DataFrame:

```
s = df2.set_index('reason_code')['reason_comment']
df1['variable'] = df1['variable'].map(s)

df1 = df1.pivot('id','g','variable').add_prefix('reason')

print (df)

g     reason1    reason2    reason3
id                                 
1   A is high  B is high  C is high
2   C is high  B is high  D is high
3   D is high  B is high  C is high
4   D is high  C is high  B is high
```

For convert `id` to column  and remove `g` use:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a lot to absorb. 

Is it possible that the final df becomes a normal pandas df (id becomes a column itself instead of a index)

Comment: Got it! im doing the steps one by one now to understand it :) Thank you!